# How to implement arabic language in ocr library android app

Tags: android, ocr

How to extract arabic text from image in ocr libary android app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract text from image Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287910/how-to-extract-text-from-image-android-app)

Answer (score 0):

Try using google vision API: https://cloud.google.com/vision/
This API supports many languages including Arabic. 
You can try the API online and upload an image that contains Arabic writing and see the results for yourself.

Comment: I havent used the library in my code yet but it lets you upload an image and shows the respond of your text. Give it a try online and see