# How to implement a search function in my Android pdf reader app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-search, pdf-reader

I am willing to add search functionality to my pdf reader.I dont know how do i achieve this functionality.Any help would be appreciated.
Note:I am using third party library to read the pdf file.
Here is the library link:
https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Is it possible to implement search functionality using this library?If not then what should be the other approach(like any java library or java code for achieving this).

Answer (score 1):

After doing some investigation about the library you provided, I found out that there have been multiple users requesting the search functionality inside of the library.

I am not familiar with the library in any way, however, if there was a way to get the text of the pdf, you can search using an `EditText` with a `addTextChangedListener`, which will iterate through the entire text of the pdf searching for the text entered.

Comment: The problem is that the library convert the pdf into bitmap form and then load it so i think this will not work.

Comment: You can try converting the bitmap to text. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287910/how-to-extract-text-from-image-android-app 
After conversion you can try to search for a word and maybe scroll to that specific word or highlight it

Comment: Thanks alot.I will try it out.Just one question is firebase ml kit free or licensed.

Comment: iirc it is free

Comment: Dont you think that library just extract the text from bitmap,it does not convert the bitmap to text form.